# How to group connection between Pods by IP using headless service in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, service

I have two deployments both with 3 replicas. I want a pod process connection with others only, independently of the number of connections and ports.

```
podConsumer1 -----> podMensageria1
podConsumer2 -----> podMensageria2    
podConsumer3 -----> podMensageria3
```

In my setup, the pod consumer connects to some Mensageria pods.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-headless-svc
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: rabbitmq
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5672
      targetPort: 5672
```

I hope someone can give me a tip

Comment: By using DNS Loopup we can connect to the Pods IP using headless service.
With headless services, DNS returns the pods' IPs, clients connect directly to the pods, instead of through the service proxy. For more detailed information on this refer to this [KUBERNETES HEADLESS SERVICE AND DISCOVERING PODS](https://www.bogotobogo.com/DevOps/Docker/Docker_Kubernetes_Headless_Service.php)